# ERR_ABORTED 429 (Too Many Requests) in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, request, http-status-code-429

While I was Running the Code and Requesting from the Server, I Got the Following Error:-

> GET https://ipinfo.io/?callback=jQuery321009066225017254137_1609854136768&_=1609854136769 net::ERR_ABORTED 429

Here is My Code

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $.get("https://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
   console.log(response.city, response.country);
   }, "jsonp");
</script>
```

**Hope Someone will be Able to Solve it!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an error. It's an expected response code.

> Free usage of our API is limited to 50,000 API requests per month. If you exceed that limit we'll return a 429 HTTP status code to you.

https://ipinfo.io/developers#jsonp-cors-requests